# Who should update the concurrency token in EF Core?

Tags: database, entity-framework-core, optimistic-concurrency, rowversion

Who should update the concurrency token in EF Core?

I am learning the EF Core through the tutorials over [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/concurrency). And I come across the concept of the concurrency tokens.

While it is clear that the row version`s value is updated by the database when either insert or update occurs, it is not clear when and by whom should the concurrency value be changed.

My assumption is that the concurrency token requires a custom solution on the database client side (the concurrency token should be updated manually before each insert or update). Is it a correct assumption or am I missing something?